# calculating cubic root in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to evaluate the following function in python:

```
f(x) = (1 + cos(x))^(1/3)


def eval( i ):
   return math.pow( (1 + math.cos( i )), 1/3)
```

why is it always returning me `1`?
I'm trying to calculate the `Right` and `Left` approximation of an integral, and latter apply `Simpson's Rule`, but `Python` does not seem to like that expression.
Help?
***Complete Code ***

```
import math

min = 0
max = math.pi / 2
n = 4
delta  = ( min + max ) / n

def eval( i ):
   return math.pow( (1 + math.cos( i )), 1/3)

def right( ):
   R = 0
   for i in range(1, n+1):
        R += eval( i )

   return R

def left():
   L = 0
   for i in range(0, n):
        print eval( i )
        L += eval( i )
```

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to define a function named eval since eval() is already in use by Python as a built-in function.

Comment: The `^` operator means "bitwise exclusive OR".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use floating point math (1 / 3 truncates to zero). Also, no need for math.pow (** for exponentiation)...

```
(1 + math.cos(i)) ** (1 / 3.0)
```

Also, `min`, `max` and `eval` are built-in functions - you are shadowing them.

Also, the extra spaces you are adding in your function call arguments are against [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (Python Style Guide). Specifically this paragraph:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements

Comment: Alternatively for Python 2: `from __future__ import division`

Comment: PEP-8 is for working on the Python code base itself.  @philippe is welcome to use whatever guidelines he'd like for his personal code. PEP-8: "This document gives coding conventions for the Python code comprising the standard library in the main Python distribution."

Comment: @Omegaman PEP-8 is widely used throughout the entire Python community.

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
1/3.0
```

instead of

```
1/3
```

in your code. Otherwise your exponent will always be `0` due to integer truncation.

Whether to use `**` or `math.pow()` is up to your preference, most would probably just use `**`.

It's probably *not* a good idea to define a function named `eval` since [**eval()**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) is already in use by Python as a built-in function.

*Background:*

Note that you could also do  `1.0 / 3`  or `1.0 / 3.0` .. as long as *one* of the operands in the division is a `float` the result will be a `float`.

However, this  `float(1/3)` would *not* work since it would convert the `0` resulting from the integer division `1/3` into a `float` giving you `0.0`

Under **Python 3.x** the division operator `/` would have worked as you expected (ie it would give you a `float` value even with two integer operands). To get integer division you would have to use `//`.

So had you run this under Python 3.x you would not have encountered this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### New in Python 3.11

The `math` module now includes a built-in [**`cbrt`**](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/math.html#math.cbrt) for cube roots, so your function can be implemented as:

```py
def f(x):
    return math.cbrt(1 + math.cos(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1/3 is an integer divide, evaluating to 0. Try 1./3

Comment: This depends on the version of Python. It changed from version 2 to 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're performing integer arithmetic where you really intend to perform floating-point arithmetic.  Try changing the [second] *1* to  *1.0*:

```
def eval( i ):
    return math.pow( (1 + math.cos( i )), 1.0/3)
```